# Why does my NumPy logspace give me an infinity array?

Tags: python, numpy

To get a logarithmic array of 1000 until 1000000000 with 23 points I wrote this code in Python:

```
import numpy as np

x4 = np.logspace(start=1000, stop=1000000000, num=23, base=10)
print(x4)
```

The results where:

```
[inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf inf]
```

How do you solve this problem and what did I do wrong in my code?

Comment: Instead of `np.logspace`, you can use `np.geomspace(start=1000, stop=1000000000, num=23)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`np.logspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html) is not doing what you think it's doing. You are expecting the effect of [`np.geomspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.geomspace.html):

```
10**np.linspace(np.log(1000), np.log10(1000000000), 23)
```

In fact, you are getting

```
10**np.linspace(1000, 1000000000, 23)
```

From the docs:

> In linear space, the sequence starts at `base ** start` (*base* to the power of *start*) and ends with `base ** stop` (see *endpoint* below).

So you probably want

```
np.logspace(3, 9, num=23, base=10)
```

Or alternatively,

```
np.geomspace(10**3, 10**9, 23)
```

The exact reason for the result can be seen with [`np.finfo`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.finfo.html):

```
>>> np.finfo(np.float_)
finfo(resolution=1e-15, min=-1.7976931348623157e+308, max=1.7976931348623157e+308, dtype=float64)
```

Since `10**1000 > 1.7976931348623157e+308`, `inf` is just a signal of the expected overflow.

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstood what logspace does. It gives you the powers, starting with `base**start`, which in your case is `10**1000`. So in your case:

```
out = np.logspace(start=3, stop=9, num=23, base=10)
```

And test:

```
plt.plot(out)
plt.yscale('log')
```

Output:

[image]